# Wall mounted Heated towel rail plug not marked

Tags: power

Looking for correct wiring configuration as this plus has not colour coding like others I have wired. I sure there must be a standard for these.

[[image: face plate front]
[[image: ][1]]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/somiC.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ze1F6.jpg)

Comment: I am quite sure that on a focused image you could see something

Comment: Are the screw terminals labeled? Is one green, one silver, and one gold?

Comment: 'Towel rail plug'? It looks like a cable outlet - not a plug. (1) What is it - a switch (not a good idea in a bathroom) or a fused outlet? (2) What are you connecting to? (3) Can you give us an in-focus photo of both sides of it? (4) What country are you in? Edit your question rather than comment.

Comment: That looks like an American  shape of faceplate. Which is a bit worrying given the EU standard wiring colours. Whatever you are doing, first check voltage compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Brown/blue and green with a yellow stripe are an EU standard.
More information on the coloring scheme can be found here:

[Wiring color codes](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/reference/chpt-2/wiring-color-codes-infographic/)

Brown is the phase (hot; black in the US), and blue is the neutral (white in the US). The green/yellow wire is the ground wire (green or bare in the US).

Answer (score 1):

What they said.
Plus:

**Do** check that towel rail rated voltage and local mains voltage are compatible.

Wire colours are as noted elsewhere.
Brown: Phase / Hot / Live
Blue:  Neutral /Return
Green-yellow: Ground.

Switch can be checked with Ohm meter and MUST be.
Bottom left two contacts are PROBABLY a SPST on/off switch BUT contact on right may be a "common" for a SPDT switch.

Most likely BUT NOT CERTAINLY terminal on right is a "loop" contact isolated from switch proper, used for joining mains and load neutrals together.
If so, usual use is to:

- Feed Phase via switch.
  Phase in to one left hand contact,
  Phase out to load on other left hand contact.
- Use floating loop terminal on right to join Neutral lead from load to Neutral lead from mains.

In such an arrangement earth is not dealt with BUT SHOULD BE USED.

3 important points:

- Use an Ohm meter to verify what all switch contacts do
- Use an Ohm meter to verify what all switch contacts do
- Use an Ohm meter to verify what all switch contacts do

Also, ensure that ground/earth on rail connects to mains ground - that your towel users' lives may be long on the land.

[image]

---

The diagram below seems likely to be correct, but may not be. Having a test meter is a near essential when doing such work. Small DMM's (Digital Multi Meter) are available at low cost. The main requirement here is the ability to measure on / off continuity of a switch. In this case, viewing what is written on the switch adjacent to each terminal would help greatly.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Russell its a great help. so basically the feed from the house live wires split the switch, so positive from house mains would go to right loop. positive from heated rail go to left and 2 neutrals bottom. or am I not correct. I don't have a metre at this time.

Comment: @Glen Completely wrong, alas. A meter costs very little at entry level and is an almost essential thing to have in such situations. | Follow what I said above and you should be OK. Do what you said and it goes bang. I'll edit my text and add a few extra words to make it clearer - the instructions per se will not change.